# Magento 2 after upgrade to 2.4.6-p1 on checkout sidebar issue

Tags: magento2, checkout-page, magento2.4.6

i have upgrade magento 2.4.6-p1, but i have some issue face-out in checkout/#shipping page on right side Order Summary "Item in cart" missing. i have attach also screenshot. please help me.

thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please check your default file **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/cart-items.html**

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<div class="block items-in-cart" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active', 'active': isItemsBlockExpanded()}}">
    <div class="title" data-role="title">
        <strong role="heading" aria-level="1">
            <translate args="maxCartItemsToDisplay" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"></translate>
            <translate args="'of'" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()"></translate>
            <span data-bind="text: getCartSummaryItemsCount().toLocaleString(window.LOCALE)"></span>
            <translate args="'Item in Cart'" if="getCartSummaryItemsCount() === 1"></translate>
            <translate args="'Items in Cart'" if="getCartSummaryItemsCount() > 1"></translate>
        </strong>
    </div>
    <div class="content minicart-items" data-role="content">
        <div class="minicart-items-wrapper">
            <ol class="minicart-items">
                <each args="items()">
                    <li class="product-item">
                        <div class="product">
                            <each args="$parent.elems()" render=""></each>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </each>
            </ol>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions-toolbar" if="maxCartItemsToDisplay < getCartLineItemsCount()">
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action viewcart" data-bind="attr: {href: cartUrl}">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'View and Edit Cart'"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> The Overwrite file in theme: **app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/web/template/summary/cart-items.html**

> Or the File is already overrated by any third-party module that is an old file version. Please update the file content with the latest range of the magento version code.

Comment: Msquare thanks for your reply, i m checking & let you know.

Comment: Msquare, its working

Answer (score 1):

**I can provide you with some general troubleshooting steps to help resolve the issue:**

- **Clear the cache:** Clearing the cache in Magento can often resolve display issues. You can do this by accessing the command line interface (CLI) and running the following command:

  php bin/magento cache:flush
- **Deploy static content:** Make sure that the static content is deployed properly by running the following command:

  php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
- **Check the theme files:** If you have made any customizations to the theme, ensure that the necessary files are present and that there are no errors in them. If you are using a third-party theme, make sure it is compatible with Magento 2.4.6-p1.
- **Disable third-party extensions:** Disable any third-party extensions temporarily to check if the issue is caused by a conflicting extension.
- **Check logs for errors:** Check the Magento logs (var/log/) and web server logs for any error messages related to the checkout or Order Summary. This can provide valuable information about the cause of the issue.
- **Magento Mode:** Ensure you are in the correct Magento mode.
- **Debugging:** Check for any JavaScript errors or console warnings in the browser's developer console (F12 key in most browsers). This might give you a clue about what's causing the issue.

Remember to take a backup of your Magento installation before making any significant changes, especially if you're going to modify theme files or disable extensions. This ensures that you can revert back in case anything goes wrong during the troubleshooting process.